# Why my app force closes?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, logcat

I making a To-do list app and when I try, it force closes. I checked variables, listeners everything and still failed to find an error. I don't know what I missed here, every thin looks perfect at least to me.

I added the logcat here

The java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public final static String STOCK_SYMBOL = "com.rashad.mytodolist.MEMO";
private SharedPreferences MemoEntered;
private TableLayout stockScrollView;
private EditText stockSymbolEditText;
Button enterStockSymbolButton;
Button deleteStocksButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MemoEntered = getSharedPreferences("stockList", MODE_PRIVATE);

    stockScrollView = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.stockScrollView);
    stockSymbolEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.stockSymbolEditText);
    enterStockSymbolButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterStockSymbolButton);
    deleteStocksButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteStocksButton);

    enterStockSymbolButton.setOnClickListener(enterStockButtonListener);
    deleteStocksButton.setOnClickListener(deleteStocksButtonListener);

    updateSavedStockList(null);
}

private void updateSavedStockList(String newStockSymbol) {
    String[] memo = MemoEntered.getAll().keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
    Arrays.sort(memo, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    if (newStockSymbol != null) {
        insertStockInScrollView(newStockSymbol,
                Arrays.binarySearch(memo, newStockSymbol));
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < memo.length; ++i) {
            insertStockInScrollView(memo[i], i);
        }
    }
}

private void saveStockSymbol(String newStock) {

    String isTheStockNew = MemoEntered.getString(newStock, null);

    SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = MemoEntered.edit();
    preferencesEditor.putString(newStock, newStock);
    preferencesEditor.apply();

    if (isTheStockNew == null) {
        updateSavedStockList(newStock);
    }

}

private void insertStockInScrollView(String stock, int arrayIndex) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View newStockRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.memorow, null);
    TextView newStockTextView = (TextView) newStockRow
            .findViewById(R.id.stockSymbolTextView);
    newStockTextView.setText(stock);
    stockScrollView.addView(newStockRow, arrayIndex);
}

public OnClickListener enterStockButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        if (stockSymbolEditText.getText().length() > 0) {
            saveStockSymbol(stockSymbolEditText.getText().toString());
            stockSymbolEditText.setText("");

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                    stockSymbolEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);

        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.Nothing);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.Enter_memo);
            AlertDialog theAlertDialog = builder.create();
            theAlertDialog.show();

        }
    }
};

public OnClickListener deleteStocksButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        stockScrollView.removeAllViews();
        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = MemoEntered.edit();
        preferencesEditor.clear();
        preferencesEditor.apply();
    }

};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    menu.add(0, 1, 0, "about My ToDo");
    menu.add(0, 2, 1, "Quit");

    return true;

}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 1:

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

        ;
        return true;
    case 2:
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

xml file :

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/stockSymbolEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" 
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/enterStockSymbolButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Button" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#006699" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stockSymbolTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/List"
            android:textColor="#000000"
             />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#006699"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/stockScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tablememo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp" 
                android:stretchColumns="yes" >
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deleteStocksButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/Button1" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

logcat for the error :

```
    02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rashad.mytodolist/com.rashad.mytodolist.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ScrollView
02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ScrollView
02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at com.rashad.mytodolist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
02-20 12:03:47.119: E/AndroidRuntime(2872):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Do you have an errorlog?

Comment: on which line you are getting the exception?

Comment: Look for "FATAL EXCEPTION" and the stacktrace below it. The part of logcat you posted is not relevant in diagnosing the crash.

Comment: there is no more log cat for this app, this is all

Answer (score 2):

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/stockScrollView"
```

...

```
stockScrollView = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.stockScrollView);
```

You cannot cast a `ScrollView` to a `TableLayout`. Hence the `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ScrollView` in logcat.

To fix it, change

```
private TableLayout stockScrollView;
```

to

```
private ScrollView stockScrollView;
```

and

```
stockScrollView = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.stockScrollView);
```

to

```
stockScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.stockScrollView);
```

There can be other problems but this is at least one step forward.

Generally, you need to learn to debug your programs yourself: When there's an exception, look for the reason and location from the stacktrace in logcat. Theorize an explanation for the exception. Test your theory by fixing the theorized problem and running the code again. Repeat as necessary.

Comment: so how can I change it?

Comment: thanks for this, and I am kinda new to xmls and java, so forgive me.